# Application security architecture framework

Tags: architecture

I'm writing a security architecture for the application I'm working with. I'm struggling  in finding a framework to follow for this task. I can find a lot of frameworks like TOGAF and SABSA that works with enterprise security, but my task is more specific to an application. 
Have anyone worked with such a framework?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for more specific application security architecture guidance, I'd be inclined to look at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) materials as they're more focused in this area.

Project like the [OWASP Developer Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Guide_Project), [OWASP Application Security Verification Standard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASVS) or [OWASP Software Assurance Maturity Model](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aSoftware_Assurance_Maturity_Model) could be of use in this context